# Strange Error in Python using BeautifulSoup Prettify method

Tags: python, text, browser, beautifulsoup

I got the following problem. I wrote a simple "TextBasedBrowser" (if you can even call it browser at this point :D). The website scraping and parsing with BS4 works great so far, but the its formatted like shit and pretty much unreadable. As soon as I try to use the prettify() method from BS4 it throws me an AttributeError. I searched quite a while on google but couldnt find anything. This is my Code (prettify() method is commented out there):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys
import os

legal_html_tags = ['p', 'a', 'ul', 'ol', 'li', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'title']
saved_pages = []


def search_url(url):
    saved_pages.append(url.rstrip(".com"))
    url = requests.get(f'https://{url}')
    return url.text


def parse_html(html_page):
    final_text = ""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
    # soup = soup.prettify()
    plain_text = soup.find_all(text=True)
    for t in plain_text:
        if t.parent.name in legal_html_tags:
            final_text += '{} '.format(t)
    return final_text


def save_webpage(url, tb_dir):
    with open(f'{tb_dir}/{url.rstrip(".com")}.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as tab:
        tab.write(parse_html(search_url(url)))


def check_url(url):
    if url.endswith(".com") or url.endswith(".org") or url.endswith(".net"):
        return True
    else:
        return False


args = sys.argv
directory = args[1]
try:
    os.mkdir(directory)
except FileExistsError:
    print("Error: File already exists")

while True:
    url_ = input()
    if url_ == "exit":
        break
    elif url_ in saved_pages:
        with open(f'{directory}/{url_}.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as curr_page:
            print(curr_page.read())
    elif not check_url(url_):
        print("Error: Invalid URL")
    else:
        save_webpage(url_, directory)
        print(parse_html(search_url(url_)))
```

And this is the Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "browser.py", line 56, in <module>
    save_webpage(url_, directory)
  File "browser.py", line 29, in save_webpage
    tab.write(parse_html(search_url(url)))
  File "browser.py", line 20, in parse_html
    plain_text = soup.find_all(text=True)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

If I include the encoding parameter in the prettify() method it throws me 'bytes' instead of 'str' object.

Comment: Could this have been before `# soup = soup.prettify()` was commented out? It looks like your `soup` variable is a string, not a soup object.

Answer (score 0):

`prettify` turns your parsed HTML object into a string, so you can’t call `find_all` on it. Maybe you just want to `return soup.prettify()`?
This might be what you want:

```py
def parse_html(html_page):
    final_text = ""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
    plain_text = soup.find_all(text=True)
    for t in plain_text:
        if t.parent.name in legal_html_tags:
            final_text += t.prettify() + " "
    return final_text
```

Comment: So its basically not possible to prettify and to extract the text? Because I need only the text of the specified text but right now its mostly given out in one gigantic, unreadable text block.

Comment: Edited. Does the new thing do what you want?

Comment: What new thing do you mean? I wanted to parse the text from the specified html tags, which works great but before saving and outputting them I wanted some kind of formatting and I thought the prettify method would help me, I didnt know that its only for prettifying html code. Its just, if you parse for example the nytimes main page, you end up with a big af text block, completely unformatted which is kinda hard to read. But thank you guys for your help :)

Comment: By ‘new thing’ I meant the changed code. `prettify` is probably best used as the final stage in processing the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You have re-assigned the soup variable into a string using the .prettify() method

```
soup = soup.prettify()
```

find_all() is a method for soup objects only

You should call find_all(text = True) first and extract all html tags with text, then you perform string operations.

Comment: Thank you, I actually found out that the prettify methods purpose is not what I thought it is. I thought its meant to format your final text output.